# is 'author' a beamer element?

Tags: beamer

I have an issue with width of the author line on the title page in `beamer` presentation and I expected to solve this problem with the adjustment through `\setbeamertemplate{author}{*new definition*}`, but I discovered that this approach doesn't work at all.

Here is just a dummy code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\author{Author1}
\setbeamertemplate{author}{useless line}
%\setbeamertemplate{title page}{useless line}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}

\maketitle

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note, that if you uncomment 4th line, you'll immediately see effect of the `setbeamertemplate` command.

So, what is the best way to get access to the `author` element definition in `beamer`?

Comment: No. `author` is not a `beamer` template. Using `author in head/foot` you can customize the color and font for the author in the headline/footline but not in the main body of the title page. The `\author` command is defined in the file `beamerbasetitle.sty`. Perhaps if you describe your problem and what you want to achieve we can give you some solution.

Comment: I have a list of authors, which requires around 85% of `\paperwidth`, but still it's longer than default `\linewidth` and I want to have that list on a single line only. Usually this issue I solve with `\adjustbox{center}{line longer than linewidth}`, but in case of `\author{\adjustbox{center}{*author list*}}` I got an error `You can't use \aftergroup` ...

Comment: OK, `\author{\makebox[0pt][c]{*author list*}}` solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why `\setbeamertemplate{author}{...}` won't work is because `author` is not a `beamer` template. Using `author in head/foot` you can customize the color and font for the author in the headline/footline but not in the main body of the title page. On the other hand, the `\author` *command*, defined in the file `beamerbasetitle.sty`, is responsible for making the preparations (through `\insertauthor`) to typeset the author information in the title page.

If you want to fit a long list of authors on a single line, you can use a `\makebox` and, depending on the theme chosen, the optional argument for `\author` to provide a sensible content for eventual footline information:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{The Title}
\author[Author One at al.]{\makebox[0pt]{Author One \and Author Two \and Author Three \and Author Four \and Author Five}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]